# "No counter 'subfigure@save' defined ". This error appear when subfloat command is used

Tags: floats, subfloats

When I use the nex code the following error is shown

***"LaTeX Error: No counter 'subfigure@save' defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.24   \subfloat
   [BT bifurcation diagram]{\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwid..."***

The code That I am using is this:

```
    \documentclass[draft]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subfig}
%para graficas

   \begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \centering
  \subfloat[BT bifurcation diagram]{\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{ZTauEquilibrio.eps}\label{fig:f1}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Divergence in non-equilibrium region for the point $\tau=-0.06$ y  $\rho=0.001$]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{ZTauEquilibrio.eps}\label{fig:f2}}
\end{figure}


    \end{document}
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `subfig` package replaces the older `subfigure` package - don't use both of them at the same time:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subfig}
%para graficas

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\centering
\subfloat[BT bifurcation diagram]{\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:f1}}
\hfill
\subfloat[Divergence in non-equilibrium region for the point $\tau=-0.06$ y  $\rho=0.001$]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:f2}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use subcaption package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Picture 2}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```